# Gitlab API Miroring dost not accept address with %20

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I am trying to create mirrors on my GitLab via API and I am able to do that just fine. Problem appears when I try to create a mirror to an address that has URL encoded space "%20" in it.

When I call git lab API with following curl:

```
curl --request POST --data 'url=https://user:password@remotegit.com/Repo%20Mirror%20Test/_git/Repo%20Mirror%20Test' --data "enabled=true" --header "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" "https://mygit.com/api/v4/projects/171/remote_mirrors"
```

I get following response:

```
{"id":171,"enabled":true,"url":null,"update_status":"none","last_update_at":null,"last_update_started_at":null,"last_successful_update_at":null,"last_error":null,"only_protected_branches":false,"keep_divergent_refs":null}
```

"url":null does not appear when I use any other address without "%20"

When I do this via UI with the same URL it works just fine. I tried to change " for ' to stop any expansion from happening but no luck. In UI I also looked to Developer tools if there is anything different but string is sent in the same format, unchanged.

GitLab server version: 15.2.2

Any ideas what could cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right the whole URL needed to be encoded, you can do that in "https://www.urlencoder.org" or in my case I needed to use it in Bash script so I installed a package "gridsite-clients" which contains "urlencode" which does basically the same thing. Once the address was encoded all worked as expected. So the final request would look like this:

```
curl --request POST --data  'url=https%3A%2F%2Fuser%3Apassword%40remotegit.com%2FRepo%2520Mirror%2520Test%2F_git%2FRepo%2520Mirror%2520Test' --data "enabled=true" --header "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" "https://mygit.com/api/v4/projects/171/remote_mirrors"
```